# how to redirect http to https permanently magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to redirect http to https permanently magento?

I have added below code but its not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```